# Why is SIF failing to create Solr core?

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore XP9 by following the installation guide as described in **Chapter 5** of the [Sitecore Experience Platform Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Initial_Release.aspx). After creating a Powershell script as described in **section 5.2.1**, when I run it, I get the following error:

[image]

I had previously installed **Solr 6.6.1** with an SSL self-signed certificate according to the following links:

- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/enabling-ssl.html
- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/installing-solr.html
- https://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/

This instance is up and running as displayed in the image below.

[image]

I don't have the slightest idea of what is going on. Anyone?

Comment: you can see on the right image you solr is not secured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SOLR instance is not secure. I recommend you install Solr 6.6.2, it works better than 6.6.1.

To make your solr instance secure please follow these steps:

Using the JDK Keytool command we can create self-signed certificates to be used by the SOLR instance. For the following steps, the following variables are used.

You should replace these variables with your applicable path when typing out the commands.

**{JAVA_HOME}** : The path where you have Java installed (e.g.C:\Program Files (x86)\jre1.8.0_131)

**{SOLR_HOME}** : The path where you have Solr installed (e.g. C:\solr\solr-6.6.2)

NOTE: The following steps are based on instructions provided by Apache (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/enabling-ssl.html) with alterations that I used to simplify the flow:

1. Open command prompt
2. Change to the Solr 'etc' directory:
   cd "{SOLR_HOME}\server\etc"
3. Execute the keygentool command

"{JAVA_HOME}\bin\keytool.exe" -genkeypair -alias solr-ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass secret -storepass secret -validity 9999 -keystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Organizational Unit, O=Organization, L=Location, ST=State, C=Country"

This will generate the keystore with a password of 'secret' as valid for localhost and 127.0.0.1. You can add other DNS and IPs as desired, or skip hostname verification. See full instructions at: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/enabling-ssl.html

4. Convert generated JKS to PKCS12

   "{JAVA_HOME}\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore -srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
5. Enter password when prompted. The password `secret` was used in the previous step. Remember to use your password instead if you changed it in the keygen command parameters.
6. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to the 'etc' directory ("{SOLR_HOME}\server\etc")
7. Double-click on the generated 'p12' file (solr-ssl.keystore.p12 if you used the default parameters from the previous steps)
8. In the dialog, specify the following values:
   Store Location: Local Machine
   File name: Leave as provided
   Password: secret
   Certificate Store: Trusted Root Certification Authorities
   Remember to use your password instead if you changed it during the previous steps.
9. Open the solr.in.cmd file for editing (e.g. {SOLR_HOME}\bin\solr.in.cmd)
10. Edit the SSL settings:

> set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
>
> set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
>
> set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
>
> set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
>
> set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
>
> set SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false

Remember to update passwords and file paths to match to the parameters you specified.

11. Restart SOLR to pick up the changes.

Comment: Many thanks, @sitecore-climber. I was missing the steps 4 to 8 in my installation process. After generating a p12 file and installing the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store, SIF was able to proceed with the Sitecore 9 installation. Just one comment on your answer, you've mentioned that I should install Sol 6.6.2. The reason why I didn't was due to the recommendation on Solr Compatibility Table https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897. Site has officially tested and recommended only the Solr 6.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the screenshot, you are missing a self-signed certificate. When the certificate is correctly installed, Chrome considers Solr admin page as "Secured" as opposed to "Not secure" that you're having at the moment.

There is already a number of powershell scripts prepared by the community that automate Solr installation and https setup. This [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8091/configuring-ssl-for-solr) mentions at least 2 scripts.

Comment: I had the self-signed certificate, but I had not installed it on my local machine.

Comment: Hence I recommend using powershell script instead of installing Solr manually :)

Comment: Hmmm. Do they have a Powershell script to install Solr?

Comment: Yes, but I realized that I haven't pasted that particular link. It's here: https://gist.github.com/jermdavis/8d8a79f680505f1074153f02f70b9105