# Is there a specific order to install Sitecore 9 XP1?

Tags: xconnect, installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm installing Sitecore 9 XP1 and facing issues with my certificate for XConnect as you can see [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8770/issues-with-xconnect-certificate-does-not-contain-private-key)

That being said, I wonder if is there a specific order to install Sitecore 9 XP1 and that's the root cause of my issue

Here's how I am trying to provisioning the XP1

1. Solr installation
2. XConnect Cores in SOLR server
3. Sitecore Cores in SOLR server
4. Generate XConnect certificate
5. Generate XConnect Collection certificate
6. SIF to install  XConnect-XP1-Collection (**Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (onPrem)_xp1collection.scwdp.zip**)

And getting error saying that the XConnect certificate does not contain private key

Should I install a different package first?

Comment: Are you manually creating your certificates?  Or using SIF to create them?

Comment: Manually creating

Comment: Do you have an XP1 install.ps1 script to share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PowerShell script provided in the section **5.2 Install Sitecore XP** of the [Sitecore Experience Platform Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/CBD83D3FE7CA470297CAA7807D1DB296.ashx), I can say that the installation order is:

1. Install Solr and enable SSL, which includes creating the self-signed certificate and installing both in Solr and in your local machine. See [Why is SIF failing to create Solr core?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/why-is-sif-failing-to-create-solr-core) for more information.
2. Install client certificate for xConnect
3. Install Solr cores for xdb
4. Deploy xConnect instance
5. Install Solr cores for Sitecore
6. Install Sitecore instance

Comment: There's a race condition in the current release of Sitecore SIF where Solr doesn't get started fast enough after the Deploy of xConnect instance and then SIF turns Solr off again during the Solr Core installation for Sitecore.  I had to change the powershell script to install all solr cores first for both Xconnect and Sitecore, and THEN installed XConnect and then install Sitecore.

Comment: My issue is while deploying the XConnect Collection, and I am getting errors on it. I'm installing Windows updates on my 2016 Server and check again, let's see.

Comment: The guide (5.2) says that this PowerShell script should be available somewhere on dev.sitecore.net - anyone found it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have Windows 10 Installed in your machine and IIS is enabled:

Steps:

1. Install Java Runtime environment 8.0 or above
2. Install SOLR (6.6.1 for Sitecore 9.0 and 6.6.2 for Sitecore 9.0 - Update 1)
3. Host SOLR on https (you may use NSSM for hosting SOLR as a windows service)
4. Install SQL Server 2017
5. Install SQL Server Management Studio
6. Enable contained Database Authentication
7. Install Sitecore 9.x by executing powershett script.

Please check the below blog for more details:

http://jitendrasitecore.wordpress.com/2018/02/14/installing-sitecore-9-0-update-1/

Comment: You should avoid "link only" answers. Try to provide all the necessary info here.