# Error While setting up SSL certificate for Solr 6.6.2

Tags: solr

I am trying to setup SSL for `solr 6.6.2` for `Sitecore 9.0.2` but getting the below error:

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image]

```
    Trusting generated SSL certificate...
    Import-PfxCertificate : An internal error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090020)
    At D:\MHMD\solrssl.ps1:59 char:9
    + $root = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $P12Path -Password $secureStr
     ...
    +         ~~~~

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-PfxCertificate], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.Impor
   tPfxCertificate
```

Comment: did you try these - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8091/configuring-ssl-for-solr
https://cmsxperience.com/2018/06/13/solr-enabling-ssl/

Comment: Yes, followed same steps

Answer (score 0):

Things that can be checked or tried:

1. Check if `JAVE_HOME` is configured properly in the environment variables.
2. Instead of running it on `localhost:8983` (or a different solr port), you could try with a new domain like `solr:8983`. You would need to add this to your host entry file and map it to `127.0.0.1` as well as make changes in your `solrssl.ps1` file.